# Не работает reject.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Хочу что бы показывалось сообщение при входе на сайт в IE 8, использую reject.js но скрипт не срабатывает в IE

Вот что подключаю:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.reject.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/main.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?> // Функция wordpress для хедера
```

Такой скрипт использую:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $.reject({
        reject: {
            msie: 8
        },
        imagePath: '/images/',
        display: [ 'chrome','firefox','safari','opera' ],
        header: 'Ваш браузер устарел!',
        paragraph1: 'Вы пользуетесь устаревшим браузером, который не поддерживает современные веб-стандарты и представляет угрозу вашей безопасности.',
        paragraph2: 'Пожалуйста, установите современный браузер:',
        closeMessage: 'Закрывая это уведомление вы соглашаетесь с тем, что сайт в вашем браузере может отображаться некорректно.',
        closeLink: 'Закрыть это уведомление',
        closeCookie: true,
    });
    return false;  
});
```

Вот какие ошибки появляются в IE 8:

```
Сведения об ошибке на веб-странице

Сообщение: Предполагается наличие идентификатора, строки или числа
Строка: 9
Символ: 197
Код: 0
URI-код: http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/apasbusiness/js/jquery.reject.min.js


Сообщение: Предполагается наличие идентификатора, строки или числа
Строка: 52
Символ: 2
Код: 0
URI-код: http://localhost/wp/
```

Comment: Какие скрипты подключаю неправильно вставилось: jquery-1.7.min.js jquery.reject.min.js и функция вордпрес <?php wp_head(); ?> подключает какой  то javascipt код